# SWITCHING NAMES IN FILES

Tags: regex

First of all let me apologize for asking this question again. I tried to find the answer, but drew a blank. I want to switch the order of words in a file such as: "dutch, abe - a blank sheet" to "abe dutch - a blank sheet". I'm using regular expressions and I seem to remember it's something like 1, 3, 2. Anyway, thank you in advance.

Comment: Each string is on a newline?

Answer (score 0):

If each string is on newline you can try like this:

Find:

```
^(\w+),\s*(\w+)(.*)
```

Replace:

```
\2 \1\3
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/SpKOHE/3

Regex:

`(\w+)` Match 1 or as many word characters and capture in group.

`\s*` Match 0 or as many whitespaces.

`(.*)` Match evertything till the end of line.

Comment: @cliffordeaton Consider [Accepting the best Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/345277)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex pattern:

```
^(\w+),?\s+?(\w+)(.*)
```

The substitution order is:

```
$2, $1$3
```

https://regex101.com/r/T3c77x/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^([a-zA-Z]+),?\s*?([a-zA-Z]+)(.*)$` and then modify your initial string to produce the output as `$2, $1$3`.

I don't know which language are you using for regex or I would have written the complete code here for you. But the logic will be similar to above.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/RZNdw2/1)

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more exact. I'm using a regular expression and I seem to remember what I need is something like (1, 3, 2). I will try your suggestion though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: nope, it didn't work. I am using a renaming program and it just copied the formula instead of the author's name.

Comment: Can you write your code here, so that I can understand where the issue is?